# Access and store {field} and {param} tags

Tags: codeigniter

In the following document,
https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks-your-own-validation-methods

There is a callback function that sets the message,

```
public function username_check($str)
        {
                if ($str == 'test')
                {
                        $this->form_validation->set_message('username_check', 'The {field} field can not be the word "test"');
                        return FALSE;
                }
                else
                {
                        return TRUE;
                }
        }
```

In the output, {field} gets replaced by the name of the 'input key'. Can anyone tell how to store this {field} tag value in a variable as I wan't to use it in my business logic.

Comment: you can add that line in the `form_validation_lang.php` like `$lang['input_1'] = 'name_you_want';` and then you can use it like `$this->lang->line('language_key');`

Answer (score 0):

The value of `{field}` is taken from the value passed via the second parameter to `set_rules()`. For instance.

$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'callback_username_check');

The word **Username** will replace `{field}`. The error message produced using the above will read.

> The Username field can not be the word "test"

Comment: OK Great info. But is there a way to store it in variable inside callback function without passing it explicitly as additional parameter. As $str provides me the value of the key. I want the key it self in a variable to use in my business logic. I know a way out like passing as an additional parameter, callback_username_check[first_name]. But I want to provide the option to the developer that if 'key name is same as column name in database then don't need to pass else pass it explicitly'. So can you help?